# Apache and mysqlamin showing blank

Tags: mysql, filezilla, xampp

Hi I am running a website for over 2 years and suddenly it showed up out of memory issue from last week. So I tried to allocate more memory but now apache and mysqladmin pages are blank and I get this error.

Apache(error.log)

```
[Tue Jan 28 13:33:24.324500 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 6908:tid 652] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Jan 28 13:33:24.355750 2020] [core:warn] [pid 6908:tid 652] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Tue Jan 28 13:33:24.449498 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 6908:tid 652] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Jan 28 13:33:24.652622 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6908:tid 652] AH00455: Apache/2.4.33 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2o PHP/7.0.30 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jan 28 13:33:24.652622 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6908:tid 652] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Mar 29 2018 11:38:15
[Tue Jan 28 13:33:24.652622 2020] [core:notice] [pid 6908:tid 652] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Tue Jan 28 13:33:24.668248 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6908:tid 652] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 1572
[Tue Jan 28 13:33:25.371369 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 1572:tid 620] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Jan 28 13:33:25.480743 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 1572:tid 620] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Jan 28 13:33:25.511993 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1572:tid 620] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Tue Jan 28 13:33:26.168240 2020] [:error] [pid 1572:tid 2004] [client 185.153.196.13:57688] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\wp-includes\\formatting.php on line 2818
[Tue Jan 28 13:33:26.168240 2020] [:error] [pid 1572:tid 2004] [client 185.153.196.13:57688] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\wp-includes\\version.php on line 1
[Tue Jan 28 13:34:31.138496 2020] [:error] [pid 1572:tid 2004] [client 115.64.88.169:58561] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\wp-includes\\formatting.php on line 2841, referer: http://www.surgicalguide.com.au/wp-admin/users.php
[Tue Jan 28 13:34:31.262618 2020] [:error] [pid 1572:tid 2004] [client 115.64.88.169:58561] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\wp-includes\\pomo\\mo.php on line 323, referer: http://www.surgicalguide.com.au/wp-admin/users.php
[Tue Jan 28 13:34:45.007539 2020] [:error] [pid 1572:tid 1992] [client 115.64.88.169:49827] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\wp-includes\\formatting.php on line 3214
[Tue Jan 28 13:34:45.020551 2020] [:error] [pid 1572:tid 1992] [client 115.64.88.169:49827] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\wp-includes\\pomo\\mo.php on line 315
```

myeql_error.log

```
2020-01-28 13:33:22 1854 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2020-01-28 13:33:22 6228 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

2020-01-28 13:33:23 6228 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2020-01-28 13:33:23 6228 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2020-01-28 13:33:23 6228 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-01-28 13:33:23 6228 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2020-01-28 13:33:23 6228 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2020-01-28 13:33:23 6228 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2020-01-28 13:33:23 6228 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2020-01-28 13:33:23 6228 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-01-28 13:33:23 6228 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2020-01-28 13:33:23 6228 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence number 12213792 in ibdata file do not match the log sequence number 100572373 in the ib_logfiles!
2020-01-28 13:33:23 6228 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite buffer...
2020-01-28 13:33:23 6228 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-01-28 13:33:23 6228 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-01-28 13:33:23 6228 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.38-83.0 started; log sequence number 100572373
2020-01-28 13:33:23 10980 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2020-01-28 13:33:23 6228 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-01-28 13:33:23 6228 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-01-28 13:33:24 6228 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.32-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Also just to add on these are list of files I have touched on but I rolled it back.

php.ini
wp_config
.htaccess